# Bad Request when accessing request.data

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I want to send data via Ajax to my Django Server. But when I want to read these data I get a bad request error back. I dont know why, other methods like request.method or request.stream work well.

This is the Ajax Call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/termin/get-journey-time/',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: {
            'method': 'get_journey_time',
            'mandant_id': 1,
            'customer_address': customer_address,
            'staff_group': staff_group_id
        },
        success: function (resultData) {
            console.log(resultData)
        });
```

This is my view for this post request:

```
class get_journey_time(generics.ListAPIView):
    """
    Handle Ajax Post to calculate the journey time to customer for the selected staff group
    """
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        body = request.data
        return Response(body)
```

I get error code 400 Bad Request. Do you know why?

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        body = request.method
        return Response(body)
```

or

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        body = request.stream
        return Response(body)
```

Work well

Comment: did you try `from django.http import JsonResponse`?

Comment: jap but same here

Comment: put a `print("foo")` function inside the `post()` to check whether the request is hiting or not

Comment: `print('foo')`works, as well as request.method or request.stream

Comment: can you add the error traceback?

Comment: it is just one line: `Bad Request: /termin/get-journey-time/`

Comment: in your django server console, there should be a full error trace.

Comment: `System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 03, 2019 - 15:17:00
Django version 2.1.7, using settings 'Animoo.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[03/May/2019 15:18:50] "GET /static/App/js/termin.js HTTP/1.1" 200 25522
Bad Request: /termin/calc-appt/
[03/May/2019 15:18:51] "POST /termin/calc-appt/ HTTP/1.1" 400 73
[03/May/2019 15:18:52] "GET /api/v1/bankholidays/1?format=json HTTP/1.1" 200 1674
[03/May/2019 15:18:52] "GET /api/v1/workitems/1?format=json HTTP/1.1" 200 898`

Comment: print/inspect `request.POST` before accessing `request.data`.

Comment: request.POST is also not working...

Answer (score 1):

You are getting HTTP 400 because your code is raising an exception. Since other methods work, it must be the `body = request.data` part. After reading the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#parseerror)
I assume there must be something wrong with parsing the data you are POSTing. Like, isn't serializer needed here?

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake.

After reading the django rest framework documentation I figured out that I have called the wrong parameters in the post method.

`def post(self, request, format=None):` instead of `def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)` worked for me.
Thanx all, best!